What is Pagurus, The Ravenous' weakness?
I'm at the point in the game where I need to fight Pagrus, The Ravenous in order to secure the third piece of the map. Nemma mentioned hearing something about him having a weakness, but I can't find any more information on that weakness. What is Pagrus' weakness that Nemma is referring to?

As comments on spoilers about Pagurus on Reddit say, it's not a weakpoint to be targetted, but, information that can be acquired in Flotsam:

Mega spoilers here, it's really fun to find it naturally.


 There's a shrimp in a sort of vase/beaker in Flotsam. If you free him, he tells you that Paragus is severely allergic to bananas. And in a way that makes it sound like it's a joke to get you killed by the developpers.


Patches is a recurring NPC in fromsoft games that has the habbit of tricking you and trying to get you killed.

From Modgrinder666 on Fri May 31 15:27:36 2024 UTC.
